# Internet connection on virtualbox works with normal wi-fi, but doesn`t when host is using iphone`s hotspot internet

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

This is different from every connection problem I've ever seen in virtualbox.
I'm using windows 11 and a kali linux virtual machine. When I connect windows to iphone's
hotspot, connection on windows works , but not inside the virtual machine.
But when i connect windows on a normal wi-fi network , it works fine on both of the machines

Comment: Can you correct your question? In Windows it works but when connecting Windows it works on both of the machines doesn't seem to maske sense.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the hypervisor (virtualbox) on Windows more than the guest OS (Kali Linux). It might be more a superuser.com question. Though there may be someone here who's seen it.